# How can I quickly/easily edit all posts with a given tag, to change some to use a different tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits, editor

Example:

On *[Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tour)* there's long been a tag, `auto-complete-mode`, which corresponds to a particular (now old) Emacs package `autocomplete.el` and its command/mode `auto-complete-mode`.

For several years now, other ways to obtain autocompletion have been available in Emacs, and the use of that old package has diminished.

But the only tag for autocompletion has been `auto-complete-mode`, so that tag has unfortunately been applied to lots and lots of questions that have nothing to do with package `auto-complete.el` and its command `auto-complete-mode`.

I've added a new tag, `autocompletion`, for the general feature of autocompletion. And I started editing posts with tag `auto-complete-mode`, to change those that have nothing to do with that package to instead have tag `autocompletion`. But this is *really* ***s l o w***.

What's an easy way to get this job done? It would be good to just (1) get the list of posts tagged `auto-complete-mode`, which is simple, and then (2) look at each of them, and just hit a key or click something once, to *replace* tag `auto-complete-mode` with tag `autocompletion`, if appropriate.

(That's what you'd do in/with an editor - query-replace. I don't use Emacs to access Stack Exchange, otherwise I'd use it to make such a replacement.)

Is there some existing shortcut to performing such an edit on a set of posts?

Comment: Moderators have the option to *merge* one tag into another - this is typically asked/requested for on [your site's Meta](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Glorfindel: What's meant by "merge" here? I want *some* of the posts with tag `auto-complete-mode` to instead use tag `autocompletion` - that's all.

Comment: OK, then a merge is not appropriate, and the only option is to go on a (manual) [tag:retag-request]. Those are usually done by the community, a handful of questions each day, to avoid crowding the homepage.

Comment: @Glorfindel: How/where to submit such a request? The tags in question are Emacs-specific, and only people in that community would be targets for such a request. What's the procedure for submitting such a request for a single site (emacs.SE)?

Comment: @Glorfindel: And why doesn't StackExchange provide a better way to carry out such a simple, if ultimately manual (in terms of judging), maintenance operation?

Comment: Don’t you have to manually review each question to ensure that the tag changes are appropriate anyway?

Comment: @joe: Please reread the request. E.g.: *"look at each of them, and* **just hit a key or click something once**, *to replace tag auto-complete-mode with tag autocompletion,* **if appropriate."**

Comment: I understand what the request is but if you are reviewing tags and redoing as needed I would think you would want to review all tags on the question and update them manually. In my mind even with manual review a system like that would lead to errors. I think it is similar to the guidelines around editing posts in that you are supposed to fix as much of the post as you can rather then just change things one at a time.

Comment: @JoeW: In the case described, the analysis of whether this tag change is needed for some question is extremely quick. But the typing and clicking needed to make just this simple tag replacement is laborious - consumes the most time. When hundreds of posts need to be edited this way it's impractical. StackExchange's UI, including reviewing and editing tools, are rudimentary/primitive - or more politely, they have room for improvement. Maybe if someone's not used to better editing tools they seem just fine...

Comment: You seem to be missing the point I was making in the last comment. When editing a post or changing tags on a question you should be reviewing it for all possible changes instead of just doing a quick look at it and only changing one of the things that may or may not be needing changed. What happens when you change this single tag and it means that the rest of them are now invalid tags? Should we just let these questions with bad tags sit around?

Comment: Or how many bad changes are going to be made because people get in robo review mode and start approving/denying changes incorrectly? It always is a major concern on some sites that people just plow through reviews like this which ends up with incorrect results. There is a reason why some of these things are designed to take a while and overall we should not be having major tag changes like this very often in the first place.

Comment: @JoeW: Your over-generalizations are completely out of context, sorry. That good editing tools enable you to quickly make wide-scale simple changes doesn't imply that you can't otherwise spend time to more slowly make more involved changes. It doesn't impose "robo review"ing.

Comment: How is pointing out that an edit to a post or a questions tags is supposed to address all issues with the post an over-generalization? It isn't a matter of editing tools being good or bad but the desire that when an edit is done to a post everything is looked at and as much as possible is fixed. This is to avoid situations where a question gets bumped to the top of the front page many times in a short period of time because of lots of small minor edits. Not to mention a mass edit like you are suggesting would flood the front page and push lots of questions off it.

Comment: @JoeW: "Overall we should not" doesn't correspond to any specific, real context - it's only about "overall". Overall? Sure. No one's suggesting otherwise. Such a general guideline doesn't serve as a rationalization that what's available now is best (can't be improved), and *one-size-fits-all*. You've learned an "overall" guideline, and that's fine. Now maybe learn that the devil's in the details - specific contexts. That you can delete a line or paragraph of text all at once isn't in opposition to the ability to delete a single character. 100 flowers, not monoculture...

Comment: Did you not see the comment from Glorfindel that included doing the edits in small numbers so that the home page was not overwhelmed with edits which can push new questions off the page before they can get noticed and answered? There are many reasons why they don't want people to mass edit posts.

Comment: As for your concern about minor edits moving a post up in the presentation list: Another missing "tool" (AFAIK) is the ability to specify an edit as "minor". Even Emacs Wiki has that feature (and users can list recent posts with or without (default) including minor edits.

Comment: "Is supposed to" is overgeneralization, yes. An overall guideline should be taken into consideration *along with* the context and specific editing aim, not just imposed in an orthodox way (and especially not just because the editing tools are limited). It's about taking the specific editing context and purpose into consideration. It "should be" for users making the changes to decide. Of course they can only decide among the tools actually available to them.

Comment: Apparently the answer to my question is *No, there is* **no** *way to quickly/easily edit all posts with a given tag, to change some to use a different tag.* I guess I'll wait a bit, to see if anyone answers. And if not, I'll add that (apparent) answer.

Comment: @Glorfindel: I agree that what you described (multiple edits by the community, few per day etc.) is a good approach. For that, I'd like get an answer to the question I asked you about a "retag request": **How/where to submit such a request?** *The tags in question are Emacs-specific, and only people in that community would be targets for such a request. What's the procedure for submitting such a request for a single site (emacs.SE)?*

Comment: Every Stack Exchange site has its own Meta, in your case it's https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The problem with your minor edit not bumping posts idea is that the concept of bumping posts on an edit is to help ensure the quality of changes by making sure that they get noticed and not just lost to time.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Yes I know that. That doesn't answer my question. Are you saying that a retag *request* should be posed as a **question** on that site?

Comment: Yes, that's what the [tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/retag-request/info) says ...

Comment: @JoeW: Either you don't want some edits moved to the top, because they are minor, or you do want them moved to the top. Either you don't want them noticed by everyone, by default, because they are minor, or you want them noticed by everyone. Did you perhaps miss the point that users would be able to either hide or show minor edits? On Emacs Wiki (a very simple site) *"users can list recent posts* **with or without** *(default) including minor edits."* IOW, let users decide how to edit (and give them better tools for that), and let users decide whether to show minor edits.

Comment: As was mentioned before edits like this are normally done in smaller batches to not overwhelm the front page with edited posts. Just because it is desired to limit how many are done at once doesn't mean that it is desired to not have them show up on the front page.

Comment: @Glorfindel: Thanks. I had already done that, but hadn't known about tag `retag-request`. FWIW, that tag wiki says nothing about posting a retag request as a question - it just says what the tag means. OK, you can only tag questions. But a request for action isn't a question.

Comment: @Glorfindel: There was no tag `retag-request` on that site. I had used tag `retagging`. I've now created also a tag `retag-request` and added that as well.

Comment: @JoeW: Once again, you seem to be showing your black-&-white orthodoxy. Limiting to few minor edits per day is *one* way to not overwhelm the displayed list, yet still record minor edits. Nothing prevents that from being employed. But better is to *also* give editors and users the ability to show/hide minor edits, at any time.

Comment: And this is an issue about how edits are designed to work with them fixing as many of the issue with a post at once and not just making a minor change. As was mentioned there is already a system in place for dealing with these retag requests it is just that it can't be done in mass as you are desiring. There is a reason that all edits bump posts to the front page and that is to get eyes on the edits and prevent someone from going around and doing "minor" edits to put in spam URLS or other types of malicious edits that would be easy to miss if not for the bump.

Comment: FWIW, mods also have asked for such features (i.e. better mass editing & tag management tool), but it just hasn't been considered by staff.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT: Good to know. Thx. I was wondering whether this had also occurred to others.

Comment: @Drew Yes, over the years, there have been multiple feature requests for all the different possibilities which have been discussed here so far.